# Add condition to where clause in q/kdb+

Tags: kdb

Table Tab

| minThreshold | maxThreshold | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10000 | 10 |

`` wClause,:enlist((';~:;<);`qty;Tab[`minThreshold]) ``

trying to incorporate maxThreshold column to where clause

```
qty >= MinThreshold
qty <= MaxThreshold
```

something like
`` wClause,:enlist((';~:;<);`qty;Tab[`minThreshold]);Tab[`maxThreshold]) ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q)Tab:([] minThreshold:500 1000;maxThreshold:700 2000;point:5 10)
q)Tab
minThreshold maxThreshold point
-------------------------------
500          700          5
1000         2000         10
q)select from Tab where minThreshold>=900,maxThreshold<=2500
minThreshold maxThreshold point
-------------------------------
1000         2000         10
q)parse"select from Tab where minThreshold>=900,maxThreshold<=2500"
?
`Tab
,(((';~:;<);`minThreshold;900);((';~:;>);`maxThreshold;2500))
0b
()
q)?[Tab;((>=;`minThreshold;900);(<=;`maxThreshold;2500));0b;()]
minThreshold maxThreshold point
-------------------------------
1000         2000         10
```

See the whitepaper for more information on functional selects:

- https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem

1. you have a Where phrase that works for [functional qSQL](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/) and you want to extend it?
2. you want to select rows of a table where the value of a quantity falls within an upper and lower bound?

If (2) you can use Join Each to get the bounds for each row, and [`within`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/within/) to test the quantity.

```
q)show t:([]lwr:1000 900 150;upr:10000 25000 500;qty:10 1000 450)
lwr  upr   qty
---------------
1000 10000 10
900  25000 1000
150  500   450
q)select from t where qty within' lwr{x,y}'upr
lwr upr   qty
--------------
900 25000 1000
150 500   450
```

Above we use `{x,y}` because in qSQL queries comma does not denote Join.

Comment: `(,)` can be used in place of `{x,y}` as well

Comment: Yes, correct i want to extend the wClause which takes the values, minThreshold and maxThreshold as conditions and pass to my logic.